# C#-UWP FolderPicker hangs on FolderOpenDialog of Windows 10

Tags: c#, uwp

The line `Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();` of the `MyPickFolderAsync()` method below is supposed to allow me to pick a folder from the default `Downloads` folder but after it opens the Windows open folder dialog (at `Downloads` folder) the dialog hangs (freezes) there and I can't select a sub-folder from `Downloads` folder. I've seen the similar issues online (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46284807/1232087) and [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/502)) but those issues seem related to older versions of `Windows 10` whereas; I'm suing the latest version `1809`.

So, what I may be missing here and how can we resolve it? The issue does seem related to me not properly using `async/await`. I tried various variations of using `async/await` but no success so far. Someone with better understanding of using asynchronous methods may help better.

Flow is as follows: I click `BtnTest` button that calls `TestAsync()` that in turn calls `MyPickFolderAsync()`. I'm using `VS2019` on `Windows10-ver 1809`

```
private async void BtnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await TestAsync();
}

private async Task TestAsync()
{
    Task<StorageFolder> pickedFolder = MyPickFolderAsync();
    await MyTestAsync(...); //this method does something with pickedFolder folder but that is not relevant to this post since we don't even get to this line in debug mode as the Windows dialog hangs before we get to this line
}

private async Task<StorageFolder> MyPickFolderAsync()
{
    Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
    folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Downloads;
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    if (folder != null)
    {
        // Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder (including other sub-folder contents)
        Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.
        FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);
        //this.textBlock.Text = "Picked folder: " + folder.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        //this.textBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled.";
    }

    return folder;
}
```

Comment: `StorageFolder pickedFolder = await MyPickFolderAsync();` Have you tried this. Your MyPickFolderAsync is not waiting for the user selection.

Comment: @Eldho Your suggestion worked (thank you). You may want to convert your `comment` to a `Response` and I will mark that as an `Answer`. Some details regarding the error (such as why using `Task<StorageFolder> pickedFolder = ...` instead of `StorageFolder pickedFolder = ...` is wrong and why we should also be using `await` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public IAsyncOperation<StorageFolder> PickSingleFolderAsync()`

When the call to this method completes successfully, it returns a `storageFolder` object that represents the folder that the user picked.

If user cancel the operation you will get the `ErrorCode`,`Status` once the task is completed.

Since you never `await the MyPickFolderAsync()`, the task is stuck in a suspended state and cannot make progress.

```
private async Task TestAsync()
{
     var pickedFolder = await MyPickFolderAsync();
}
```

Comment: I've edited my comment above. In your response could you please also explain why using `Task<StorageFolder> pickedFolder = ...` in my call to `MyPickFolderAsync();` is wrong? Note that in that line of my code I am using `Task<StorageFolder>` instead of `StorageFolder` that (according to your suggested code) is not correct.

Comment: your returning the storageFolder from the MyPickFolderAsync

Comment: @nam Since you never `await` the `MyPickFolderAsync()`, the task is stuck in a suspended state and cannot make progress.

Comment: @Eldho I've further explained the issue in my `Response` below. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First thanks to the user [Eldho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56512341/1232087) who helped me resolve the issue and we should `give credit where credit's due`.

However, for the benefit of some other readers of this post it "may be" worth mentioning that I was getting the following error when I was using `await` on the following line of code of `TestAsync()` method (that had to be corrected):

```
Task<StorageFolder> pickedFolder = MyPickFolderAsync();
```

When I used `await` on the above call, I got the following error:

[image]

So, after reading response from user `@Eldho`, I had to remove the `Task<...>` from the above line of code and add `await` to that line (thanks to `@Eldho`).